# JQuery not working for input name as array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello i am created one table with zero row and a "add row button" in which when user click on "add row buttton" one extra row for that table in created using javascript.  In table row i am creating three input field as name, address and mobile number.  Now i want, when user changing moblie number filed then the jquery must be call as shown in bellow but its now working what should i do??

The code for creating table row and jquery which is not working as below..

```html
<form action "..." mehtod="post">
  <table id="table1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>address</th>
        <th>mobile</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
  </table>

  <button id="insertrowbutton" type="button" float: right;" onclick="insertrow()">Insert new row</button>

  <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>

<script>
  function insertrow() {
    document.getElementById("table1").insertRow(-1).innerHTML = '<td> <input type="text" name="name[]"> </td><td> <input type="text" name="address[]"></td>  <td><input type="number" name="mobile[]"</td>
  }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('input[name^="mobile"]').on('change', function() {
    alert($(this).val());
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Its because its a dynamic inserted element and that does not exist in the dom at the time.  use `$(document).on('change', 'input[name^="mobile"]',function()`

Comment: Offtopic, you have `float: right;"` in your button... I think you are missing `style="`

Answer (score 0):

You're creating new elements all the time, so the change handler isn't bound to them. Try this instead, which will ensure that the change listener is applied.

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[name^="mobile"]',function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this and it will work:

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[name^="mobile"]', function() {
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

Please note you have invalid code in your button `float: right;"`

**demo**

```js
function insertrow() {
  document.getElementById("table1").insertRow(-1).innerHTML = '<td> <input type="text" name="name[]"> </td><td> <input type="text" name="address[]"></td>  <td><input type="number" name="mobile[]"</td>'
}

$(document).on('change', 'input[name^="mobile"]', function() {
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action "..." mehtod="post">
  <table id="table1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>address</th>
        <th>mobile</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
  </table>

  <button id="insertrowbutton" type="button" onclick="insertrow()">Insert new row</button>

  <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```